# Eclipse JavaFX - Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, runtime-error

I'm trying to run a simple JavaFX script just to get myself up and running with it, but am returning `java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found` (full stack trace below). I've followed all the steps from the [openjfx.io documentation](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) under **JavaFX and Eclipse > Non-modular from IDE**, which include:

1. Create a new user library for JavaFX including all jar files from the SDK
2. Create a new Java project. (Note that unlike the documentation which includes a **Main.java, Controller.java**, and **hellofx.fxml**, I only created one Java file for simplicity, as I also could not quite figure out how to add an fxml file).
3. In the build path of the new Java project, confirmed that both JavaFX library and JavaFX SDK are included in the Classpath (**JRE System Library [JavaSE-16]** is currently the only thing sitting in the Modulepath).
4. In the Java file Run Configurations, added the VM arguments `--module-path /path/to/javafx-sdk-17/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml`, replacing `path/to` with the actual path to my SDK.

When I run the project, I get the following error printed to the console:

```
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  es2, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:283)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:254)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:264)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:291)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:163)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:659)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:410)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1071)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:95)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1071)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:276)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:291)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:163)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:659)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:410)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
    ... 5 more
```

The simple code I'm trying to run is the following:

```
package miditest;
 
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
 
public class JavaFX extends Application {
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
 
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
            }
        });
        
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);

 Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The only similar issue I have found is [here](https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/issues/237), which suggests downloading JavaFX as jmods instead of the SDK, but this did not fix the issue for me. The only other thing I can think of is that the fxml file is a pre-requisite to running JavaFX, but the documentation doesn't necessarily seem to suggest that.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated, and please let me know if there's any other info I can provide.